# Better way to use closure in a curry?

Tags: javascript, currying

I have a JavaScript object like this:

```
var functionsMap={
    functionName1:function(a, b, curryData){},
    functionName2:function(a, b, curryData){}
}
```

I have the following curry situation:

```
var currySomeFunctions = function(functionsMap, curryData) {
    var wrappedSet = {};
    for (var functionPropertyName in functionsMap) {
        var element = functionsMap[functionPropertyName];

        wrappedSet[i] = function(element) {
            return function(a, b) {
                return element(a, b, curryData);
            }

        }(element)
    }
    return wrappedSet;
}
```

As you can see, I have wrapped my final function in two function bodies. As you might expect, I forgot, and relied on the closure only to find that all of the resulting curried functions referred to the last 'element' function. (Ahh, closure!). Realizing this, I had to add another scope so that element would be bound.

But `return function()( return function(var){} }(var)` Seems cumbersome.

I wonder if any of you geniuses can tell me how smart people do this?

Comment: Does your platform support `let`?

Comment: @rhashimoto, not consistently. This particular function is running on the web.

Comment: @Gothdo, a bit snippy aren't we? My tag is "currying", not "curry". Since you're so knowledgable, though, do you have any advice about the question I asked?

Comment: @tqwhite Then I would probably use `let` and a ES6 compiler like Babel or Closure Compiler for deployment. A beneficial side effect is you'll get access to all kinds of other language improvements. Regarding your question tagging - your original tag was wrong; the commenter edited the appropriate tag in. Their request seems reasonable to me.